# Liturgical or church German

Tags: word-usage, formality

In a church setting,

- Is there a liturgical form of German for a pastor or
  priest to use during the service?
- Is it more appropriate to use formal or poetic forms of speech for
  everyone, anyone, or no one?
- Is "Du" or "Sie" more appropriate among parishioners both with each
  other and when addressing the pastor or priest? And does this change
  outside the church setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

zu 1)

Es gibt verschiedene Kirchen, und jede pflegt ihre eigene Kultur. Geht man vom dt. Sprachraum aus, und dem speziellen Begriff "Kirche", im Ggs. zu "Moschee" oder "Synagoge", so könnte sich Deine Frage implizit auf die 2 großen, christlichen Religionen beziehen, die aber auch mehr oder weniger eigene Subkulturen ausbilden.

Insofern diese ritualisierte Texte über lange Zeit unverändert verwendet werden, bilden sich da sicher auch Formeln und Begrifflichkeiten heraus, die mehr oder weniger exklusiv im religiösen Raum anzutreffen sind, aber von einer "liturgischen Form des Deutschen" wird man aus 2 Gründen kaum sprechen können:

1. Ist da kein übergeordneter Fundus, aus dem sich alle Kirchen gemeinsam bedienen, d.h. was in der einen Kirche üblich ist ist es in der anderen womöglich nicht, und zwar umso weniger, je weniger die Organisationen miteinander verwandt sind.
2. Ist diese Sprache nicht exklusiv für eine religiöse Gemeinschaft, sondern eher kennzeichnend für die Epoche aus der die Formulierung stammt. So werden Formeln auch in Kirchen aktualisiert, bevor sie gar nicht mehr verstanden werden - die Bibel selbst aber bleibt davon wohl eher unberührt, wie auch uralte Texte, wie der Rosenkranz. Ich glaube die meisten Gläubigen hätten Schwierigkeiten zu erklären, was "gebenedeit" überhaupt heißen soll, aber das alte Gebet wird nicht umgetextet - kommt vielleicht aber auch irgendwann.

In der kath. Kirche hört man beispielsweise "Gehet hin in Frieden!". Die Worte selbst sind profanes Deutsch. Theoretisch könnte man sich von seinen Freunden auch im Alltag so verabschieden, aber es tut niemand. "Eine Sünde beichten" ist ein christliches Konzept, aber wird im übertragenen Sinne dennoch auch außerhalb der Religion benutzt, ebenso kann eine Umweltschutzorganisation davon sprechen die Schöpfung bewahren zu wollen, ohne damit sagen zu wollen, dass sie wirklich an einen Schöpfungsprozess glauben.

Es gibt also keine scharfe Abgrenzungsmöglichkeit.

zu 3)

Die Gemeinden sind unterschiedlich, und während man hier vielleicht alle *Brüder und Schwestern* duzt, auch wenn man keinen davon kennt, und alles Erwachsen sind, man sie also außerhalb der Gemeinde nicht duzen würde, so wird es in vielen Gemeinden auch sein wie überall: Die Leute machen es mit sich selbst aus, und duzen, wen sie länger kennen, und zu dem eine freundschaftliche Beziehung besteht. Strenge Orden mögen aber strenge Regeln pflegen.

zu 2)

Eine speziell poetische Sprache benutzt man nicht außerhalb formalisierter Rituale, abseits alter Gebete und Gesänge. Man muss nicht sagen "Das Kirchenfenster zeigt einen Leu" wo ein Löwe zu sehen ist.

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with the catholic church in Germany, but I think the same things may apply to other christian denominations.

> Is there a liturgical form of German for a pastor or priest to use during the service?

No. However, some of the texts spoken have not changed over a long time and sound a little bit old fashioned. Example: `Lasset uns danken dem Herrn unserm Gott.` A more "modern" version would be: `Danken wir dem Herrn unserem Gott.`

> Is it more appropriate to use formal or poetic forms of speech for everyone, anyone, or no one?

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Usually the people attending mass will only speak their part of the "script" (style: see first part of my answer). Priests will adapt the style of their sermon if talking(/preaching to younger people/childs.

> Is "Du" or "Sie" more appropriate among parishioners both with each other and when addressing the pastor or priest? And does this change outside the church setting?

There are no special rules which apply here. Priests will addressed with "sie" like any other figures of authority.